# Keep persistent variable in Android app

Tags: android

In one of my App, I would like to give a feature as a trial for only 20 attempts. Once the user wants to access the feature for the 21st attempt, he/she will be prompted for in-App purchase.

My question is how can I make this variable persistent so that even if the user uninstalls the app and re-installs, the counter does not reset and takes the last value before the uninstall.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Backup API and backup your data online. It is very easy to use and here is tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html

The disadvantage of this method is that user can disable backups in phone's settings.

Another method requires you to send data to server. I would suggest to use parse.com since it does not require you to write any server code, they have very easy-to-use library for Android and their free plan is very generous. Here is a little tutorial:
https://parse.com/tutorials/get-started-with-android

You can send some sort of unique id (device or account specific) and counter to the cloud every time user triggers your trial feature. Also you can query your counter from the cloud when application launches the first time.

To create that unique id you can approach with few methods:

Try to obtain 64-bit unique number, which is generated when device first boots:

```
String androidID = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Note that it was reported that for some device this value might be null. You can verify your androidID variable and if it is null, you can try another method that will allow you to access user's primary e-mail (you probably want to hash it prior to sending it your server).
Also make sure to add **android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS** permissions to your manifest file:

```
final Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
for (final Account account : accounts) {
    if (Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
        final String email = account.name;
        // hash email and use it
    }
}
```

if email cannot be obtained - you might also want to try to get device id from telephony manager:

```
// For CDMA phone getDeviceId() is equal to value request for Secure.ANDROID_ID
final TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
final String deviceId = telMgr.getDeviceId();
```

(don't forget to add **android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE** permission to your manifest)

Hope that it gave you enough information to add trial functionality into your code.

Also if your in-app purchase is actually a subscription, then Google already implemented trial functionality for you:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html
(search for **free trial**)

Comment: Sorry for coming back so late. Finally decided to go for the backup option. If that works fine, then OK otherwise will try to use the second option on saving at Parse.com

Answer (score 0):

You have no way of maintaining anything locally for the user if they uninstall or reinstall the application.

If you need the uninstall/re-install requirement, this is counter that will need to be logged on your back-end rather than on the device. You can do this by storing the [device's id](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) on your server and incrementing your ticker when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I simply define a serializable Expiration object that I store to SD with a dot in front of it to make it hidden.

The object contains time of creation and other metadata.

When the app starts, it checks whether Expiration exists, if not it is create. This way I always know the exact time when the app was installed, despite uninstall/reinstalls.

The downside to this method is that it requires some sort of external storage as we want to go outside of the standard app folder of the internal storage, which is wiped upon uninstall.

To circumvent this, you could look for some way of getting/giving a device a unique id, that remains the same after reinstall, and upload the data to a server. This has the benefit that the user cannot reset the expiration by wiping the SD either.